# Fancybox not open PDF error Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox-2

i found some really interesting code on this web on how to open a PDF inside Fancybox iframe, but I want to use inside a CSS Menu that I generated through PHP, and get this message through Google Console: **Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined**

Here's my php code:

```
echo "<li class ='pdf' ><a href='http://assets/newsletters/temp/".$myissue."' > Issue# ".$filename."</a></li> ";
```

And in the Fancybox i have the following code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".pdf").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    type : 'iframe',
    width: 800,
    height: 1000,
    fitToView : true,
    autoSize : false,
    href: this.href,
    content : '<embed src="' + href + '#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
   'onClosed': function() {
     $("#fancybox-inner").empty();
   }
  });
  return false;
 }); // pdf 
}); // ready

</script>
```

I need help so I can load a different PDF everythime I make a click.

**UPDATE**
So I changed the content with the file I want to see, and it works. So my problem still being the dynamic Href that I dont know how to pass it to fancybox

```
content : '<embed src="http://assets/newsletters/temp/Newsletter_1.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
```

Comment: Have you tried applying fancybox directly to the element rather than within the "click" event of jQuery.

$('.pdf').fancybox( ...

Comment: Yes I do, i have a test link. And it doesn't open on Fancybox, it goes to a new window, full screen and when I look at the debugging console i get that same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you either use the `href` API option or the `content` option.

In your code above, you have set the `href` but later the `content` option overrides it.... I am guessing that you thought that by doing `href: this.href`, you were actually setting the value of `href` as variable and then passing it to the `content` statement but that is not the way it works, sorry.

Also, you are mixing options for v1.3.x and v2.x, which are incompatible.

I think you shouldn't over complicate things and simply do :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pdf").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width: 800, 
        height: 1000, 
        fitToView: false, // false will display the exact size you set above
        autoSize: false
        // you don't need the following :
        // href: this.href,
        // content : '<embed src="' + href + '#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=75,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
        // onClosed is for v1.3.x and doesn't work with v2.x
        //'onClosed': function() {
        //$("#fancybox-inner").empty();
        //}
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2pqBW/1/)**

Comment: Im using Fancybox 2.14, and how's the content get into the fancybox window?

Comment: @Nick : the content comes from the `href` in the hyperlink, which is a PDF file, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but when I tested I didn't work. Came up a message saying that cannot display the content. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, I tried your Jsfiddle, when it opens it just show an spinning animation and doesnt do anything else, an I tested it on my code and I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `

Comment: I tried it on a regular link, and I get this message on the console: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://assets/newsletters/temp/Newsletter_2013_2.pdf".`

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my last problem on this link by JFK:
https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/579
Which solves the Chrome/IE Header issue.

And my final fancybox code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pdf").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width: 800, 
        height: 1000, 
        fitToView: false, 
        autoSize: false,
        iframe : {
        preload: false
    }
    });
}); // ready
```

Also I made some adjustments on my php code as well:

```
echo "<li><a class ='pdf' href='http://assets/newsletters/temp/".$myissue."' > Issue# ".$filename."</a></li> ";
```

Thanks @JFK